# connection sql database in qt in visual studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

i'm starting to program in visual Studio C++ (2013) and i'm using Qt(5.5.0) for user interface .
i'm trying to connect to my sql server database (sql server 2012) .

it should be simple based on documentation . this is my code :

```
#include "qt_test1.h"
//#include "ui_qt_test1.h"
#include <qmessagebox.h>
#include <qfiledialog.h>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSql\qsql.h>
#include <QtSql\qsqldatabase.h>
#include <QtSql\qsqlerror.h>
#include <qdebug.h>

qt_test1::qt_test1(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

}

qt_test1::~qt_test1()
{

}

// when button clicked try to connect to database
void qt_test1::on_btnShowHello_clicked()
{

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("mydb");
    db.setDatabaseName("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\\MSSQL\\DATA\\qt_test_db");

    bool ok = db.open();
}
```

well when i try to debug i get this weird errorrs . its kind of missing dll thing which i dunno if its my code problem or qt installation error .

errors :

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl
>   QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase(void)" (__imp_??1QSqlDatabase@@QEAA@XZ)
>   referenced in function "private: void __cdecl
>   qt_test1::on_btnShowHello_clicked(void)"
>   (?on_btnShowHello_clicked@qt_test1@@AEAAXXZ)  E:\Project\qt_test1\qt_test1\qt_test1.obj   qt_test1
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool __cdecl QSqlDatabase::open(void)"
>   (__imp_?open@QSqlDatabase@@QEAA_NXZ) referenced in function "private:
>   void __cdecl qt_test1::on_btnShowHello_clicked(void)"
>   (?on_btnShowHello_clicked@qt_test1@@AEAAXXZ)  E:\Project\qt_test1\qt_test1\qt_test1.obj   qt_test1
>
> Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl
>   QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(class QString const &)"
>   (__imp_?setDatabaseName@QSqlDatabase@@QEAAXAEBVQString@@@Z) referenced
>   in function "private: void __cdecl
>   qt_test1::on_btnShowHello_clicked(void)"
>   (?on_btnShowHello_clicked@qt_test1@@AEAAXXZ)  E:\Project\qt_test1\qt_test1\qt_test1.obj   qt_test1
>
> Error 5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class QSqlDatabase __cdecl
>   QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(class QString const &,class QString const
>   &)" (__imp_?addDatabase@QSqlDatabase@@SA?AV1@AEBVQString@@0@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: void __cdecl
>   qt_test1::on_btnShowHello_clicked(void)"
>   (?on_btnShowHello_clicked@qt_test1@@AEAAXXZ)  E:\Project\qt_test1\qt_test1\qt_test1.obj   qt_test1
>
> Error 6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: static char *
>   QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection"
>   (__imp_?defaultConnection@QSqlDatabase@@2PEADEA)  E:\Project\qt_test1\qt_test1\qt_test1.obj   qt_test1
>
> Error 7   error LNK1120: 5 unresolved
>   externals E:\Project\qt_test1\x64\Debug\qt_test1.exe qt_test1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not your code, nor the Qt installation. You just don't understand how C/C++ compiles programs. I suggest you do some research into how the precompiler, compiler and linker work in order to fill in your knowledge gap.

In short, any time you get a "unresolved external symbol" error, this is an error generated by the linker and it means you've left some kind of library out of the project settings.

Qt comes with a whole range of modules, and these are organised into different libraries. The `QSql` module is just one of them.

If you have Qt's Visual Studio Add-in, this is easy to fix: just right-click on your project, select `Qt Project Settings`, and select `SQL` on the `Qt Modules` tab.

If you do not have the Add-in installed, you'll have to add the dependencies manually.

Right-click on your project, select `Properties`. 
Expand `Configuration properties`, then expand `Linker` and select `Input`.
In the `Additional Dependencies`, add:

1. Qt5Sqld.lib to the Debug configuration
2. Qt5Sql.lib to the Release configuration

Answer (score 1):

Your project may miss QtSql.lib dependency. Somewhere in project configuration in VS you should have possibility to add linker additional dependencies - this library should be located in your Qt installation directory (Qt/lib). Hope it helps.